# Question on vector cross product.

Tags: vector-spaces, cross-product

Show that $\big((\mathbf{u} \times (\mathbf{u}\times \mathbf{v})) \times \mathbf{v}\big) \times (\mathbf{u} \times \mathbf{v})=0$.

---

From [wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cross+product%5Bcross+product%5Bcross+product%5B%7Bu_1%2Cu_2%2Cu_3%7D%2Ccross+product%5B%7Bu_1%2Cu_2%2Cu_3%7D%2C%7Bv_1%2Cv_2%2Cv_3%7D%5D%5D%2C%7Bv_1%2Cv_2%2Cv_3%7D%5D%2Ccross+product%5B%7Bu_1%2Cu_2%2Cu_3%7D%2C%7Bv_1%2Cv_2%2Cv_3%7D%5D%5D), it gives zero but there's no details. How to prove this?

Comment: For details you've to buy the pro feature of W|A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the identity
$$\textbf{A}\times (\textbf{B}\times \textbf{C})= (\textbf{A}.\textbf{C})\textbf{B}-(\textbf{A}.\textbf{B})\textbf{C}$$
we get,

$\begin{align}
((\textbf{u}\times(\textbf{u}\times \textbf{v}))\times \textbf{v})\times(\textbf{u}\times \textbf{v})\\&=(((\textbf{u}.\textbf{v})\textbf{u}-(\textbf{u}.\textbf{u})\textbf{v})\times\textbf{v})\times(\textbf{u}\times \textbf{v})\\&=((\textbf{u}.\textbf{v})(\textbf{u}\times\textbf{v})-(\textbf{u}.\textbf{u})(\textbf{v}\times\textbf{v}))\times(\textbf{u}\times \textbf{v})\\&=(\textbf{u}.\textbf{v})(\textbf{u}\times\textbf{v})\times(\textbf{u}\times \textbf{v})=0\\
\end{align}$

Comment: Tip: for a nicer looking dot product you can use ```\boldsymbol{\cdot}```. It looks like $\underline{u} \boldsymbol{\cdot} \underline{v}$

Answer (score -2):

**Hint**:

$a\times b=0$ if and only if $a$ and $b$ are parallel.